# Displaying inline columns space created

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```css
.row {
  background: gray;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.col-md-6 {
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div>Row1</div>        
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Dummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy Text </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
     <div>LeftRow2</div>        
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div>Riight Row2</div>        
    </div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

I need this not to have the space like in the photo, but the left col to go up and to have the same height
[image]

I need this way because on responsive I need it to be like it is now like this, left column and right column below it 
[image]

I tried the other way 
like this

```css
.row {
  background: gray;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.col-md-6 {
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div>Row1</div>
     <div>Riight Row2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Dummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy Text 
      
      </div> 
   </div>      
</div>
```

The second way I achieve what I want but then in responsive the right column it is not right below the left column it is like this, does anyone know how to solve this thank you.  [image]

Comment: Can yo please explain that in which layout which div should display. with some testing text and not this long text.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something like what you're inquiring?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).on('resize',function(){ 
if ($(window).width() < 960) {
$('#row1').after($('#dummy'));
 } else {
   location.reload(); 
  $('dummy').removeAttr('id');
 }
 }); 
});
```

```css
.red-border {
  border: solid 1px red;
  background: gray;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="row1" class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="red-border"> Row1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="red-border"> LeftRow2</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="dummy" class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="red-border"> Dummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy TextDummy Text</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="red-border"> Riight Row2</div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```